# Can't deny access to role in web.config authorization element

Tags: .net, web-config, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I would like to know if it is possible to **deny** a specific **role** in web.config authorization section **for WebAPI**?

I've got following configuration, but it's not working (however I'm getting a HTTP 200 instead of *Unauthorized*) :-(

```
<authorization>
  <deny roles="Locked" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"?

Comment: I'm getting a HTTP 200 response if I try to call an API method with a user which has the role 'Locked' instead of some "Unauthorized" response.

Comment: Try with roles=".\Locked" and tell me what happens. And please, try also to deny all users with "*" just to test if authorization is well configured.

Comment: role=".\Locked" doesn't change behavior. When I deny all users I get an HTTP 302 redirect and then HTTP 200 (which seems to be correct)

Comment: Which kind of authentication are you using? Are you completerly suer that the logged in user is authenticated and has that role?

Comment: Please add `<deny users ="?" />` as the first authorization entry to ensure the user is authenticated.

Comment: I'm using "forms authentication". And yes - the logged in user has this specific role. I'm using some kind of custom token validation in WebAPI, so maybe that's the issue.. But my initial question was only if authorization also works for WebAPI via web.config? Or has it to be configured via FilterAttributes? I fear I have some error in my thinking about this whole concern :-/

Comment: (If I deny users="?" I get an HTTP 302 and then HTTP 200 (same as when I deny all users))

Comment: You're smelling the error. The problem is that your authorization must be happening after you set the role to the user. There are a zillion ways to do authorization and authentication in Web API, so, without additional information, it's impossible to give more insight in an answer